# How to do faster language detection using Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am using Dask for parallel computation and want to detect the language of sentences in a column using `langdetect`. However, I still can not gain any speed in getting the language of the rows in the column.

Below is my code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_csv('name.csv')# has a column called short_description
def some_fn(e):
    return e['short_description'].apply(langdetect.detect)

data['Language'] = data.map_partitions(some_fn, meta='string')# adding a new column called Language.
```

This csav file has 800000 rows each containing approx. 20 words long sentences.

Any suggestion how I can achieve language detection more faster because currently it takes 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

By default dask dataframe uses a thread pool for processing.  My guess is that your language detection algorithm is written in pure Python (rather than C/Cython like most of Pandas) and so is limited by the GIL.  This means that you should use processes rather than threads.  You can ask Dask to use processes by adding the `scheduler="processes"` keyword  to any compute or persist calls

```
df.compute(scheduler="processes")
```

More information on Dask's different schedulers and when to use them is here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer. I will try and get back to you soon. :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I am getting 7 minutes difference on processing 300,000 rows. It took earlier 48 mins and now 41 with `scheduler`. Do you think this is fine or can it be enhanced more?

Comment: For more information on understanding performance I recommend https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html